# iterate through nested form elements in jquery

Tags: jquery, function, each, loops

im sorry if this was posted already i have been looking to no avail..

I just want to know how to loop through nested form 'elements' (elements being not only the strict form elements like input tags but other html elements as well) in jquery.
Currently i have this piece of code to do it:

```
$('#'+arguments[i].formid).children().each(function(){ 
    var child = $(this);
    alert(child.attr('id'));
    if(child.is(":input")) { alert(child.attr('id'));
     if(child.attr('id')!='') eval("p."+child.attr('id')+"='"+child.attr('value')+"'"); 
    }

       if(child.is(":textarea")) {
     if(child.attr('id')!='')  eval("p."+child.attr('id')+"='"+child.attr('value')+"'"); 
    }
   });
```

it does not work when my form contains other elements like this:

```
<form>
    <div id='tabs'>
        <ul>...</ul>
        <div id='tab-1'>
               <input type='text' id='fname' />
               <textarea id='desc' ></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

please help...

Comment: First of all: never use eval in JS. Second: what exactly are you trying to achieve? Usually there is a better way then to iterate over all elements.

Comment: i'm using eval() cause my object properties are dynamic and are based on the id's of the form input. Or are there any other ways to do this without using eval()?

Comment: thanks for the tip. i just somehow needed a way to pass an object from php to javascript like from php i throw this value to javascript: {lastpage:'main',var:foo,var2:bar} and in javascript: eval("p="+<?=$thatobject?>); this way i can record the last session values for use on the current requesting page.. does that make sense? i guess im not really good in this..

Comment: You don't have to use eval here. A simple `echo "p = " . $thatobject;` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in a recursive function.

```
function doStuff(child) {
  if(child.is(":input")) {
     ...
  }

  if(child.is(":textarea")) {
    ...
  }
}

function walk(children) {
  if (typeof children == "undefined" || children.size() === 0) {
    return;
  }
  children.each(function(){
    var child = $(this);
    if (child.children().size() > 0) {
      walk(child.children());
    }
    doStuff(child);
  }
}

walk($('#'+arguments[i].formid).children());
```

**EDIT**: I just figured out, what you are trying to do and you can break it down to this

```
var p = {};
$('#'+arguments[i].formid + " input[id], #"+arguments[i].formid + " textarea[id]").each(function(){
  var child = $(this);
  p[child.attr("id")] = child.attr("value");
});
```

You should probably read more about jQuery [selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors).

Comment: wow. thanks man! that solved it and even removed a few lines of code. You are right i really need to read more about jquery selectors but i cant find a complete example for so many conditions you can encounter that will be specific to my own requirements.. jquery website gives examples but are just basic to using $("#formid>input").each(func... i guess i was looking for an explanation of what you can do within the $() braces that i was never able to find..

Comment: If this fixed your problem, you could mark this question as solved by clicking the green check mark next to my answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [contents()](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/contents) (and filter out text nodes if needed) or [find('*')](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/find#expr) to get all elements, though I dislike the use of wildcards.

```
 $('form').contents()
          .filter( function() { return this.nodeType == 1; } )
          .each(...);
```

or

```
 $('form').find('*')
          .each(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Came back to correct myself :) jQuery Rocks!
So after a crash course here is the same thing in jQuery ...

```
/*
    menu.jq     : main menu jQuery for ekerner.com
    Author      : 'Eugene Kerner' <ekerner@ekerner.com>
    Date        : 16-12-2009
    Dependencies: jQuery javascript lib
                : menu.css
                : an unordered list structure as per the below Example.
                : a javascript call to menu.init(menuId, selectedMenuItemsArray) as per the below Example.
    Notes       : if your menu link has an onclick that returns false then it needs to call menu.init before returning (see Example).
    Example     : -
    <ul id="mainMenu" class="menuItems">
      <li>
        <a href="/">Menu Item</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/webpage" onclick="window.open('/webpage'); menu.init('mainMenu', ['Menu Item', 'Sub Menu Item']); return false;">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){menu.init('mainMenu', ['Menu Item'])});</script>
*/

var menu = {
  selectedClass : 'selected',
  animateSpeed  : 'fast',
  selectedLinks : [],
  init : function(menuId, selectedLinks)
  {
    $('#' + menuId).children('li').each(function(){
      var menuItem       = $(this);
      var menuLink       = menuItem.children('a:first-child');
      var subMenu        = menuItem.children('ul:last-child');
      menu.selectedLinks = selectedLinks;
      menu.applySelectedClass(menuLink);
      if (subMenu.length == 1) {
        menuItem.hover(
          function(){menuLink.addClass(menu.selectedClass); subMenu.slideDown(menu.animateSpeed)}, 
          function(){subMenu.slideUp(menu.animateSpeed); menu.applySelectedClass(menuLink)}
        );
        subMenu.find('a').each(function(){menu.applySelectedClass($(this))});
      }
    });
  },
  applySelectedClass : function(menuLink)
  {
    ($.inArray(menuLink.html(), menu.selectedLinks) > -1) ? menuLink.addClass(menu.selectedClass) : menuLink.removeClass(menu.selectedClass);
  }
}
```

And here is the css in case anyone wants to make use of it ...

```
/*
    menu.css - main menu cascading style sheet for ekerner.com all media
    'Eugene Kerner' <ekerner@ekerner.com>
    14-12-2007
*/

.menuItems, .menuItems li, .menuItems li ul, .menuItems li ul li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.menuItems, .menuItems li ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.menuItems {
  background: url(/shared/images/menu/menu_button_bg.png) repeat-x;
  height: 30px;
}
.menuItems:after { 
  content: ".";
  height: 0; 
  clear: both; 
  display: none;
}
.menuItems li {
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
}
.menuItems li a {
  color: #0d2a86;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  height: 24px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
  display: block;
}
.menuItems li a:hover, .menuItems li .selected {
  background: url(/shared/images/menu/menu_button_bg_selected.png) repeat-x;
  color: #518ed3;
}
.menuItems li ul {
  position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    border: 1px solid #e0e7ef;
    border-top: 0;
  display: none;
}
.menuItems li ul li {
  width: 77px;
  clear: both;
}
.menuItems li ul li a {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 18px;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 2px;
  border: 0;
}
.menuItems li ul li a:hover, .menuItems li ul li .selected {
  background: #e0e7ef;
}
.visible {
  display: block;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if you need the jQuery, see domIterator example below ...

```
/*
    menu.js     : main menu javascript class for ekerner.com
    Author      : 'Eugene Kerner' <ekerner@ekerner.com>
    Date        : 14-12-2007
    Dependencies: menu.css
                : an unordered list structure as per the below Example.
                : a javascript call to menu.init(menuId, selectedMenuItemsArray) as per the below Example.
    Notes       : if your menu link has an onclick that returns false then it needs to call menu.init before returning (see Example).
    Example     : -
    <ul id="mainMenu" class="menuItems">
      <li>
        <a href="/">Menu Item</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/webpage" onclick="window.open('/webpage'); menu.init('mainMenu', ['Menu Item', 'Sub Menu Item']); return false;">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">menu.init('mainMenu', ['Menu Item']);</script>
*/

var menu = {

  selectedItems : [],

  init : function(menuId, selectedMenuItems)
  {
    this.selectedItems = selectedMenuItems;
    var menuItem = domIterator.getFirstChild(document.getElementById(menuId));
    while (menuItem) {
      var menuItemLink = domIterator.getFirstChild(menuItem);
      var subMenu      = domIterator.getNextSibling(menuItemLink);
      this.applySelectedClass(menuItemLink);
      if (subMenu) {
        menuItem.onmouseover = function(){menu.showSubMenu(this)};
        menuItem.onmouseout  = function(){menu.hideSubMenu(this)};
        var subMenuLinks = subMenu.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (var i = 0; i < subMenuLinks.length; i++)
          this.applySelectedClass(subMenuLinks[i]);
      }
      menuItem = domIterator.getNextSibling(menuItem);
    }
  },

  applySelectedClass : function(menuLink)
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.selectedItems.length; i++) {
      if (menuLink.innerHTML == this.selectedItems[i]) {
        menuLink.className = 'selected';
        return;
      }
    }
    menuLink.className = '';
  },

  showSubMenu : function(menuItem)
  {
    domIterator.getFirstChild(menuItem).className     = 'selected';
    domIterator.getLastChild (menuItem).style.display = 'block';
  },

  hideSubMenu : function(menuItem)
  {
    domIterator.getLastChild (menuItem).style.display = 'none';
    this.applySelectedClass(domIterator.getFirstChild(menuItem));
  }

}; // end menu

var domIterator = {

  getFirstChild : function(elem)
  {
    if (elem) return domIterator.continueUntilType1(elem.firstChild, 'next');
  },

  getLastChild : function(elem)
  {
    if (elem) return domIterator.continueUntilType1(elem.lastChild, 'previous');
  },

  getNextSibling : function(elem)
  {
    if (elem) return domIterator.continueUntilType1(elem.nextSibling, 'next');
  },

  continueUntilType1 : function(elem, direction) 
  {
    while (elem && elem.nodeType != 1)
      elem = elem[direction + 'Sibling'];
    return elem;
  }

}; // end domIterator
```